# ASP.NET webforms: set cookie using jQuery on the OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, jquery, cookies, webforms

Consider the scenario where:

- an ASP.NET webform page has a DropDownList and a ListView.
- this DropDownList must set a cookie value on its `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event.
- the DropDownList is also set to `AutoPostBack="True"` to force the ListView to reload using the DropDownList's new value.
- the page is referencing current JQuery libraries, including the [great set of cookie plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

This code will be used in the assignment of the value of the cookie:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie('cookieName', 'theValue', { path: '/', expires: date });
```

**Question**: Can you suggest how to have the DropDownList's value extracted and saved to a cookie using jQuery? Super bonus points for an answer including how to call the post-back method to rebind the ListView! I would definitely love to save a post-back 'flash' for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For getting value of DropDownList:

```
var ddlVal = $('#<%= ddList.ClientID %>').val();
```

2) Loading ListView:

a. For this I will suggest consulting Dave's postings at his site [Encosia](http://www.encosia.com).

b. Rick Strahl also has great post on is [blog](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jquery/jquerypart2.aspx) regarding using jQuery ajax

c. Muhammad Mosa has [post](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/GridView-Grouping-Master-Detail-Drill-Down-Using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) describing Master-Detail scenario with ajax

Comment: Thanks Village. For others, can you perhaps adjust the code to remove the space between the pound and the percent?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following will save the value to a cookie on the change event:

```
$("#" + <%=YourDropDownList.ClientID %>).change(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie('cookieName', $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: date });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="TestDropDownList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="FirstText" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="SecondText" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="ThirdText" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="FourthText" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#<%= TestDropDownList.ClientID %>').change(function(e)
        {
            var selectedValue = this.value;
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            $.cookie('cookieName', 'theValue', { path: '/', expires: date });

        });
    });     
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Raghav! Nothing was done with `selectedValue` in the `change` function, though :)